# Get records of max date for every week in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
date     | data
-----------------
1/1/2017 | a
-----------------
1/2/2017 | b
-----------------
1/3/2017 | c
-----------------
1/7/2017 | d
-----------------
...
-----------------
2/2/2017 | a
-----------------
2/2/2017 | b
-----------------
```

I need to get the data of max date for each week available in the table. The dates can be presented many times, some dates might be missing, and weeks might not be added with all seven days.

The first and probably the easiest solution that comes to mind is something like this:

```
select maxdate, data from (
select max(date) as maxdate from mytable group by DATEPART(wk, date)
) t1, maytable
where mytable.date = t1.date
```

But I was told there's a better solution without using max function. Is that even possible? Is there any better way that the above?

This is a hypothetical question and the above query might not be 100% correct as I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [common table expression (cte)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) you can get the last date and related columns for each week like so:

Using `row_number()` will let to get just one row for the last `[date]` of each week. If you need all rows where the `[date]` is the last date of the week, you can use [**`rank()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) or [**`dense_rank()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) instead of `row_number()`.

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by datepart(week,[date]) 
      order by [date] desc)
  from mytable
)
select *
from cte 
where rn = 1
```

---

or without the cte like so:

```
select *
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by datepart(week,[date]) 
      order by [date] desc)
  from mytable
  ) as cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks man, why didn't this come to my mind? BTW, is it better performance than using aggregation function?

Comment: @Lamar I can't really say if it would perform better or not, you would have to test each on your data. Although I believe this will perform a single index scan instead of the two index scans (or index scan +  index seek) for your other query (since you are using a function on [date] you won't be able to use an index seek on [date] for the max() query)... but I really can't be sure without seeing the execution plans for both.

Comment: Thank you anyway.